# манифест видит firefox, но не видит chrome, opera, может кто сталкивался?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

[image]
не могу  добавить расширение для браузеров, я добавил, но он работает только на firefox, с другими manifest.json  не работает

Comment: На этом сайте вопрос должен быть на русском языке. Или вы хотите таким образом его удалить?)

Comment: Почитал правило. Спасибо) не так понял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хромовые браузеры не до конца поддерживают спецификацию расширений.

Переменную `browser` нужно заменить на `chrome`.

Попробуй что-то вроде

```
if (browser == undefined) { let browser = chrome }
```

Comment: спасибо большое!